# How to copy struct type (not value) being different type, but with same fields

Tags: rust

That's not regarding `Copy` trait. I thought about it while designing API, where different requests have same fields. I don't want to copypaste declarations (since that would require copy-pasting & later synchronising e.g. validations), but don't want to use same types for different interfaces to prevent occasional confusion. But it's really generic problem. Here's the illustration.

We have two structs:

```rust
struct DataCreateRequest {
    name: String
    // ... 100 more fields
}

struct DataUpdateRequest {
    name: String
    // ... 100 more fields
}
```

What I would like to do is similar to `type` aliasing, but to make types distinct, something like this:

```rust
struct DataCreateRequest {
    name: String
    // ... 100 more fields
}


clone_type DataUpdateRequest = DataCreateRequest; // could be some macro?
let upd: DataUpdateRequest = DataCreateRequest { ... }; // compiler error, since those are different types
```

So that we reduce duplication, and still re-specialise them if different request appears later.

Any ideas? Any trait, wrapper, macro magic comes to mind?:)

Comment: why don't use have a common type share by your two structs ?

Comment: Alexey, not exactly. I've checked that one. I know there's no concept of inheritance :) That's more about building cutting down _unnecessary_ duplication without compromising types.

For sharing types (as composition) - that would change flat structure.

Comment: One thing I got is to create generic & parametrise it with Unit enum, but that requires embedding marker::PhantomData<...> inside, since you can't have unused type in generic.

Comment: `struct Data { name: String, ... } struct DataCreateRequest { d: Data } struct DataUpdateRequest { d: Data }`. Then you either use it as `req.d.name` (not a big deal) or add a couple of helper functions `fn data(&self) -> &Data { &self.d } fn data_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Data { &mut self.d }`.

Comment: When wrapping just a single field, I tend to use tuple structs: `struct DataCreateRequest(Data);`. The field can be accessed with `request.0`.

Comment: @BallpointBen: I used to do that too. But too many times I had to add a new field, and then replace all uses of `.0` for `.data` (or add a `.1`, ugh!), so nowadays I write tuple structs more sparsely.

Comment: You could shoot yourself in the foot by doing something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=de2b9a77ed10190b0c5593e9a45ba1f0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways that might prove useful, but in general a struct cannot "inherit" from another struct in an OOP way.

One way is with wrapper types:

```rust
struct LargeStruct {
  // lots of fields
}

struct Request(LargeStruct);
struct Response(LargeStruct);

fn foo(request: Request) -> Response {
  Response(request.0)
}
```

This prevents accidentally passing a `Request` where a `Response` is expected, and probably the easiest way.

A macro could also work:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
  ($name:ident) => {
    struct $name {
      // fields
    }
  }
}

// then create your structs:
foo!(Request);
foo!(Response);
```

Personally this seems like a bit of a hack, and you essentially "hide" from the compiler the fact that `Request` and `Response` have the same fields, so if you wanted to trivially convert a `Request` to a `Response` you'd need something like this:

```rust
fn foo(request: Request) -> Response {
  Response {
    field1: request.field1,
    // etc as long as you can tolerate
  }
}
```

Comment: That's something. Not exactly what I thought about, but very close. Thanks much! :)